# Remove All Elements on the Page that Contain a Specific Word:

Tags: jquery

What I am trying to do is remove all the elements on a Google result page that contain a specific word. However, it only is removing one element.

```
$("div[class*='IsZvec']:contains('Example')").remove();
```

Comment: Did you try $("div.IsZvec:contains('Example')").remove(); ?

Comment: @FMoosavi I got it to work now using that. However, I only just realized now that only removes one element rather than all elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$("div.IsZvec").remove(":contains('Example')");
```